# Gaining speed for further space travel

Tags: speed, distance, space-travel

With the recent discovery of the new solar system with viable planets for sustainable life, a thought of prior discussions intrigued me. Now, please understand that I have no engineering background, science degrees, etc. So I figured I would ask the question in hopes that it would raise thought and discussion to further its potential from others who may have more understanding and background; I thank you in advance for advice.

The discussions have been had and shown to support that an Electromagnetic launching system would greatly improve our ability to reach spacial orbit, as well as be able to transport larger items into space without loss of momentum from the carrying of fuel. I've always considered this a wonderful premiss, as it would allow us not only improved opportunity on a reusable launching method at a lower cost, but also decrease environmental impact from burning of fossil fuels. Removing the human aspect of this to avoid G factor concerns, even the launch of satellites, probes, and unmanned missions would benefit from this significantly.

My question comes once we are in space. We had never launched from outside the atmosphere any manned missions (from my understanding, and I may be wrong). The issue being largely that physics does not provide an option that we would not send the launching station hurtling in the opposite direction. Since the use of a rail gone removes the contact between the launch medium, and the vessel itself, which removes friction and allows for greater velocity with less resistance; could this be used once in space. If a vehicle could be placed in space, and launched on a secondary electromagnetic platform from space itself, would it not be possible to increase flight speeds in space, without need for fuel loads (other than to slow down upon arrival and course correction). Further the lack of friction would also lower the amount of force pushing against the launch medium in space, allowing for an improved control of what force was put against it, decreasing the risk for a space station.

I'm curious if this is possible and would allow for increased speed, further flight, and potential decrease of time to explore other systems, even if only by probe or satellite. Thoughts?

Comment: Might [space.se] be better suited for this question?

Answer (score 1):

> launched on a secondary electromagnetic platform from space itself, would it not be possible to increase flight speeds in space, without need for fuel loads

Nope. The platform itself is a fuel load; it has to get there somehow. Imagine a Russian doll setup of nested rail guns - the outermost rail gun has to propel all N-1 guns inside it. So you have the same exponential "fuel" requirement as for conventional rockets, except that instead of liquid fuel you have rail guns. I haven't done the math but I'm betting nested rail guns are a lot less efficient.